# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:\"\", local:\"Request\"). Expected elements are (none)

Tags: java, jaxb

I have been trying to unmarshal an XML using JAXB library. The XML is fetched from S3. We have an XSD in place which we are using at multiple place(working fine while marshalling into the same XML). Following is the piece of code:

```
S3Object xml = s3.getObject();
final InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(xml.getObjectContent(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance();
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Request pojo = (Request) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```

Jaxb v2.3.1 is used.

Stack Trace:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:\"\", local:\"Request\"). Expected elements are (none)\n\tat com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:744)\n\tat com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:262)\n\tat com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:257)\n\tat com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:124)\n\tat com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1149)\n\tat com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:574)\n\tat com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:556)\n\tat com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:168)\n\tat java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)\n\tat com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:258)\n\tat com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:229)\n\tat javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:170)\n\tat javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:219)\n\tat
```